# sympy: How to simplify this expression

Tags: python, sympy, limit, simplify, infinity

with sympy I solved an equation for a parameter (`x1` in this case) and then substituted another parameter `c2` by 0 (in the real solution).

```
import sympy as sp
c1, c2, x1, F_C = sp.symbols("c1, c2, x1, F_C", real=True)
F_C_ex = c1*x1+c2*x1**3
F_C = sp.Symbol("F_C", real=True)
sol = sp.solve(F_C_ex-F_C, x1)[0]
```

Here is what my `x1` looks like after `sp.solve`:

[image: sol]

As you can see, `c2` is in more than one denominators. Now I substitute `c2` for 0:

```
sol.subs(c2, 0)
```

The result from the substitution should be `x1 = F_C/c1` (can be seen from the original expression), but sympy doesn't get to this point. The result has some infinity symbols in it:

[image: subs]

Is there a way to simplify the equation further?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. E.g. x2 seems unused. Why is it part of your program? What is the formula you're trying to solve? The result is correct after `sol.subs(c2, 0)`, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I edited my entry and added a picture of what I get at the end.

Comment: The result that you get is valid for almost all possible values of the symbolic parameters but not for `c2 = 0` since that sets the leading coefficient for the cubic polynomial to zero. You can substitute `c2=0` first and then call solve to get the result you want.